# Dark-theme in angular/material2 is not dark

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am working with angular/material2 and I am trying to get a dark theme. 
Following the doc at [https://material.angular.io/guide/theming](https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.css) I defined my custom `theme.scss` as follows:

```
$dark-primary: md-palette($md-pink, 700, 500, 900);
$dark-accent:  md-palette($md-blue-grey, A200, A100, A400);
$dark-warn:    md-palette($md-deep-orange);

$dark-theme: md-dark-theme($dark-primary, $dark-accent, $dark-warn);

@include angular-material-theme($dark-theme);
```

The primary, accent and warn color appears as defined in my custom theme, but I don't see a dark theme (i.e. black background and foreground color changed accordingly).

In the [example provided](https://github.com/jelbourn/material2-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.css) along with the docs I saw that the background has been set through a css class, but that is not the behaviour I would expect;  `dark-theme` seems to me a specific "kind" of theme with a proper level of automation.

Am I wrong ? Anybody can help me to clarify this issue ?

Comment: So the script never loads, or it loads but doesn't apply correctly?

Comment: Seems to me it doesn't apply correctly. But I m not sure which behavior I should expect (basically to get a dark foreground and so on

Comment: I'm not sure about the current theme.. When I want to use a generic dark theme for my ng2 projects, I use bootstrap with a colour palette from https://bootswatch.com/ . That way I get all of my responsivness and colouring in only 2 lines in my `angular-cli.json`. Can't help you anymore than that though sorry. - dark theme https://bootswatch.com/slate/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was trying to use angular/material2 but maybe it is still a bit immature

Comment: I am not familiar with using angular/material2 - goodluck though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Finally, if your app's content is not placed inside of a mat-sidenav-container element, you need to add the mat-app-background class to your wrapper element (for example the body).

So if you're not using the **mat-sidenav-container** component, you need to add the Angular Material 2 background class to your HTML body like:

```
<body class="mat-app-background">
```

Comment: And if you have this class on the body and it's *still* not working..?

Answer (score 0):

Definitely I was wrong !!!
Dark theme works ... but only when inside a **md-** selector such as md-card.
Setting a body background color can be done only with css.

Comment: Has this been fixed? Nothing under $mat-dark-theme-foreground and $mat-dark-theme-background seem to work.

Comment: In angular/material2 the variable names are prefixed with **$md-**; $mat- prefix  probably is in previous version for Angularjs.
Don't know if this can help

Comment: Sorry. You are right. With the latest version of  angular/material (2.0.0- beta.2) the prefix is **mat** and no more **md**.

In answer to your question: I have solved my problem simply putting in mytheme.scss 

**body {  background-color: #212121;}**